# Is the secondary replica of Basic Availability Group readable

Tags: sql-server

I would like to replace Database Mirroring with Basic Availability Group because mirroring is deprecated and I cannot use the mirror server for load balancing.

But I am not sure if the secondary replica of Basic Availability Group is readable.

Please let me know.

The whole purpose of replacing DB Mirr. with BAG is to have the secondary replica in readable state.

We are running SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition SP2-CU6.

Your responses will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**No** - SQL Server Basic Availability Groups do not support read-only secondary replicas.

See the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15) for details and note the second bullet point under "Limitations".

Comment: My question is regarding BAG (Basic Availability Group), not AAG (Always-On Availability Group) as I am running SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition.

Comment: @Saif Apologies I have updated the answer.

Comment: I was confused because somebody said to me that SQL Server 2016 standard edition supports secondary readable replica from SP2

Comment: According to the documentation, it applies to all currently supported versions.